# Expandable row using nztable from ngzorro expands in single column. why?

Tags: angular

I have used `nztable` from `ngzorro` package. I tried using expandable row. When I tried the same code from the example given in the website, the expandable row isn't working properly. The expanded row displays itself in single `<td>` not in entire `<tr>`.
I dont know what I'm missing.

**app.component.html**

```
<nz-table #nzTable [nzData]="listOfData" nzTableLayout="fixed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th nzShowExpand nzWidth="60px"></th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let data of nzTable.data">
      <tr>
        <td nzShowExpand [nzExpand]="expandSet.has(data.id)" (nzExpandChange)="onExpandChange(data.id, $event)"></td>
        <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.age }}</td>
        <td>{{ data.address }}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr [nzExpand]="expandSet.has(data.id)">
        <span>{{ data.description }}</span>
      </tr>
    </ng-container>
  </tbody>
</nz-table>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  onExpandChange(id: number, checked: boolean): void {
    if (checked) {
      this.expandSet.add(id);
    } else {
      this.expandSet.delete(id);
    }
  }
  listOfData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'John Brown',
      age: 32,
      expand: false,
      address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park',
      description: 'My name is John Brown, I am 32 years old, living in New York No. 1 Lake Park.'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Jim Green',
      age: 42,
      expand: false,
      address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park',
      description: 'My name is Jim Green, I am 42 years old, living in London No. 1 Lake Park.'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Joe Black',
      age: 32,
      expand: false,
      address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park',
      description: 'My name is Joe Black, I am 32 years old, living in Sidney No. 1 Lake Park.'
    }
  ];
```

[Click here to view the result of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhvMw.png)